# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference.EditText is initialized

Tags: java, android, android-studio, parsing

I got The **Error** while making an **Instagram clone**
I have **initialized the EditTexts**
I don't Know Why I get this
I cant add Code so will add it in comment
[My Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DuV29.png)
[My Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mZbTG.png)

**My Java Code**

```
package com.example.instagram;

    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
    
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    
    import com.parse.ParseException;
    import com.parse.ParseUser;
    import com.parse.SignUpCallback;
    import com.shashank.sony.fancytoastlib.FancyToast;
    
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
      private Button btnSignUp,btnLogIn;
      private EditText edtUsername,edtPassword,edtEmail;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setTitle("Sign Up");
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
              edtEmail = findViewById(R.id.edtEmailAdressSignUp);
              edtUsername = findViewById(R.id.edtUserNameSignUp);
              edtPassword = findViewById(R.id.edtPasswordLogin);
              btnSignUp = findViewById(R.id.btnSignUp);
              btnLogIn = findViewById(R.id.btnLogIn);
              btnLogIn.setOnClickListener(this);
              btnSignUp.setOnClickListener(this);
    
        }
    
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
           switch (view.getId()){
               case R.id.btnSignUp:
                   final ParseUser appUser = new ParseUser();
                   appUser.setEmail(edtEmail.getText().toString());
                   appUser.setUsername(edtUsername.getText().toString());
                   appUser.setPassword(edtPassword.getText().toString());
                   appUser.signUpInBackground(new SignUpCallback() {
                       @Override
                       public void done(ParseException e) {
                           if (e == null){
                               FancyToast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),appUser.getUsername() + " is Signed Up",FancyToast.LENGTH_LONG,FancyToast.SUCCESS,true);
                           }
                           else{
                               FancyToast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Something went wrong: " + e,FancyToast.LENGTH_LONG,FancyToast.WARNING,true);
                           }
    
                       }
                   });
                   break;
               case R.id.btnLoginA:
                   break;
    
           }
        }
    }
```

**My XML Code**

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#F05644"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">
    
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnSignUp"
            android:layout_width="404dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="34dp"
            android:background="#4568FC"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="Sign UP"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="36sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.85" />
    
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edtEmailAdressSignUp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="101dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="101dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Enter Your Email Adress"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textColorHint="#fff"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btnSignUp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
    
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:background="#F05644"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/instagram" />
    
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnLogIn"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="41dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="55dp"
            android:background="#98BB00"
            android:text="Log In"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="36sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btnSignUp"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />
    
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edtUserNameSignUp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Enter Your User Name"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textColorHint="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView2" />
    
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edtPasswordSignUp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="89dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="61dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="112dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="34dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Enter Your Password"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textColorHint="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/edtEmailAdressSignUp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.421"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/edtUserNameSignUp"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.812" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**My Log**

```
    2020-07-15 12:34:15.118 10378-10378/? E/ample.instagra: Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x8000
    2020-07-15 12:35:16.066 10378-10378/com.example.instagram E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.instagram, PID: 10378
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference
        at com.example.instagram.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:41)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7125)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7102)
        at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:801)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27336)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

Comment: Post your code and your error, not images please!

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide additional code, XML, and logs. Please don't post them in comments.

Answer (score 0):

Your password edit text id is wrong

```
edtPassword = findViewById(R.id.edtPasswordSignUp);
```